# ExpiredAuthenticationToken in FunctionApp

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops, azure-functions

I have a powershell script that connects to the ADO API and shows me a pool of agents. When I run it locally it works for me, but unfortunately there is already a bug in Function App
401 Unauthorized

```
{
   "error": {
     "code": "ExpiredAuthenticationToken",
     "message": "The access token expiry UTC time '12/22/2022 2:49:41 PM' is earlier than current UTC time '12/22/2022 2:53:08 PM'."
   }
}
```

This is a new generated PAT and it is active.

Script:

```
$personalToken = "t0k3n"
$patToken = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($personalToken)"))
$repoHeader = @{"Authorization"="Basic $patToken"}
Write-Output $repoHeader
$repoUrl = [string]::Format("https://dev.azure.com/org/_apis/distributedtask/pools?api-version=5.1")
Write-Output $repoUrl
$output = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $repoUrl -Method Get -ContentType "application/json; charset=utf-8; api-version=6.0" -Headers $repoHeader -MaximumRedirection 10
Write-Output $output
foreach ($outputValue in $output.value)
{
    Write-Output $outputValue.name
}
```

I have no idea why this works locally and not in Function App

Comment: You need to start the powershell script by right click on Powershell shortcut and select Run As Admin.

Comment: @jdweng but its wokr on my local machine, not on Function App in Azure

Comment: Are you *sure* you're using the updated pat token? You might be able to list the current tokens with `GET https://vssps.dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/tokens/pats?api-version=7.0-preview.1` and check the `ValidTo` property to see expiration dates

Comment: This issue should not comes from the azure devops side, if PAT of azure devops org expired, it will only return 401 but no response body back. Your issue should related to powershell azure function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may seem strange.. But it was enough to refresh the page, because Cloud Shell has a certain time of operation, after which it throws you out of the session..

Comment: Cloud Shell is is recycled after 20 minutes of inactivity.